# jexcel add dropdown list to one row only

Tags: javascript

How can I add dropdown list to a single row in a jexcel table? 
I have managed to add dropdown list to different columns by stating the "columns" variable like this :

```js
$('#reportCD').jexcel({
  url: 'update.php',
  colWidths: [150 <?php echo $cwOut; ?>],
  colAlignments: ['left', 'left'],
  allowInsertRow: false,
  allowDeleteRow: false,
  columns: [{
    type: 'text',
    readOnly: true
  }, {
    type: 'dropdown',
    source: [{ 'id': '', 'name': 'Normal' }, { 'id': 'B', 'name': 'B' }, { 'id': 'I', 'name': 'I' }, { 'id': 'BR', 'name': 'BR' }, ]
  }],
  columnSorting: false,
  onchange: change
});
```

But I need the dropdown list to be row-based, not column-based. I cannot find any documentation about this. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on Paul's input to use the data-x and data-y values I was able to solve this challenge by adding some custom code and altering the jexcel.js file slightly.

The page looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jexcel.js"></script>
<script src="https://bossanova.uk/jsuites/v2/jsuites.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v3/jexcel.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bossanova.uk/jsuites/v2/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style> 
.popover2 {
    display: block; top: 60px; left: 460px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0px;
    z-index: 1010;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: normal;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="custom"></div>


<p id="demo"></p>

<select id="locality-dropdown" name="locality" class="popover2" style="visibility:hidden;">
</select>


<script>
var data2 = [
    ['PHP', '14:00', 'Text field'],
    ['Javascript', '16:30', ''],
];

var customColumnTwo = {

    // Methods
    closeEditor : function(cell, save) {
        var testx1 =  cell.getAttribute('data-x'); //Get data-x value from cell
        var testy1 =  cell.getAttribute('data-y'); //Get data-y value from cell
        var e = document.getElementById("locality-dropdown"); //Define custom selection

        //Find cell that will use custom dropdown based on data-x and data-y
        if (testx1 == 2 && testy1 == 1) {
            var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text; //Define value of custom cell
        } else {
            var value = cell.children[0].value; //Define value of non-custom cell in same column
        }

        cell.innerHTML = value; //Set value of cell
        e.style.visibility = 'hidden'; //Hide dropdown after select
        return value; //Return value

    },
    openEditor : function(cell) {
        var testx1 =  cell.getAttribute('data-x'); //Get data-x value from cell
        var testy1 =  cell.getAttribute('data-y'); //Get data-y value from cell

        // Create input
        var element = document.createElement('input');
        element.value = cell.innerHTML;
        // Update cell
        cell.classList.add('editor');
        cell.innerHTML = '';
        cell.appendChild(element);

        //Find cell that will use custom dropdown based on data-x and data-y
        if (testx1 == 2 && testy1 == 1) {

            var e = document.getElementById("locality-dropdown"); //Define custom selection
            e.style.visibility = 'visible'; //Show dropdown on select

                //Construct custom dropdown
                let dropdown = $('#locality-dropdown');
                dropdown.empty();
                dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Select...</option>');
                dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
                            const url = 'json/columnType.json'; //Deine data source of the dropdown list
                            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
                    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.abbreviation).text(entry.name)); //Append data to dropdown
                })
                });         
    }
        // Focus on the element
        element.focus();
    },
    getValue : function(cell) {     
        return cell.innerHTML;
    },
    setValue : function(cell, value, save) {

        var testx =  cell.getAttribute('data-x'); //Get data-x value from cell
        var testy =  cell.getAttribute('data-y'); //Get data-y value from cell
        if (testx == 2 && testy == 1) {
        var e = document.getElementById("locality-dropdown");
            var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            return value;
        } else {
            cell.innerHTML = value;
        }  
    }  
}

myTable = jexcel(document.getElementById('custom'), {
    data:data2,
    columns: [
        { type: 'text', title:'Course Title', width:300 },
        { type: 'text', title:'Time', width:100},
        { type: 'text', title:'Custom data', width:300, autocomplete:true, multiple:true, editor:customColumnTwo}, // Remote source for dropdown
     ]
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The JSON data that populates the custom dropdown is (columnType.json file):

```
[
{"name": "TOT", "id": "TOT"},
{"name": "SUM", "id": "SUM"},
{"name": "UNIT", "id": "UNIT"},
{"name": "BUDGET", "id": "BUDGET"}
]
```

And finally, the corrected code in the original jexcel.js file is done by replacing the code:

```
else if (obj.options.columns[i].type == 'dropdown' || obj.options.columns[i].type == 'autocomplete')
```

to also include the new custom field upon validation:

```
else if (obj.options.columns[i].type == 'dropdown' || obj.options.columns[i].type == 'autocomplete' || (obj.options.columns[i].editor == customColumnTwo && td.getAttribute('data-x') == 2 && td.getAttribute('data-y') == 1))
```

This last bit is just to make sure the dropdown-sign is populated in the custom cell to indicate that there is a dropdown-option to the user.

Now, the styling of the custom dropdown can/shopuld be improved as it is not dynamic in this example, so feel free to style the dropdown yourself.

I hope this will help others in the future!

Comment: this would not be recommended because you need to keep merging your local with new updates and new versions. You can archieve the same result using the editor extensions and keep customizations out of the core files.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is creating a custom column and checking the data-y data-x to render accordingly. Here is how to create a custom editor example.

```
<html>
<script src="https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v3/jexcel.js"></script>
<script src="https://bossanova.uk/jsuites/v2/jsuites.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v3/jexcel.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bossanova.uk/jsuites/v2/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.js"></script>

<div id="custom"></div>

<script>
var data2 = [
    ['PHP', '14:00'],
    ['Javascript', '16:30'],
];

var customColumn = {
    // Methods
    closeEditor : function(cell, save) {
        var value = cell.children[0].value;
        cell.innerHTML = value;
        return value;
    },
    openEditor : function(cell) {
        // Create input
        var element = document.createElement('input');
        element.value = cell.innerHTML;
        // Update cell
        cell.classList.add('editor');
        cell.innerHTML = '';
        cell.appendChild(element);
        $(element).clockpicker({
            afterHide:function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // To avoid double call
                    if (cell.children[0]) {
                        myTable.closeEditor(cell, true);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        // Focus on the element
        element.focus();
    },
    getValue : function(cell) {
        return cell.innerHTML;
    },
    setValue : function(cell, value) {
        cell.innerHTML = value;
    }
}

myTable = jexcel(document.getElementById('custom'), {
    data:data2,
    columns: [
        { type: 'text', title:'Course Title', width:300 },
        { type: 'text', title:'Time', width:100, editor:customColumn },
     ]
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Will this work for older versions of jexcel, or is it required to have V3?

Comment: Paul, this will make the whole column the same. From your example, my question is how to get the custom value ONLY for the clocl option related to the "Javascript" row. The first row should stay static.

Comment: I would recommend you update to v3. In the example I gave you, you will be able to based on the data-x or data-y render different components. cell.getAttribute('data-x') you give you that information.